# How to ensure radiobuttons are unchecked by default when under the same formgroup in angular 2+?

Tags: angular

The data are bound to the radio buttons through data from the database (Web-API). My full codes are as follows:

component.html

```
        <!-- list of Questions -->
    <div formArrayName="questions">
   <!-- <div *ngFor="let que of Questions; let k=index"> -->
    <div *ngFor="let question of Ques ; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" >

    <!-- The repeated questions template -->
  <h4>Question #{{i + 1}}</h4>
 <div style="margin-left: 1em;">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="center-block">
       <input class="form-control" formControlName="ques" disabled>
     </label>
    </div>


 <div class="form-group radio" *ngFor="let choice of question.choices ">
      <input type="radio"  formControlName="choices"
          class="custom-control-input" [value]="choice">
      <label>{{choice.choiceText}}</label>
    </div>
```

component.ts

```
export class CheckListFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  Ques: Questions[];

  Questions: any = [];

  choices: Choices;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
          private checklistservice: ChecklistService) { 
    this.CreateForm();

   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.checklistservice.getQuestions(1).subscribe(res =>{ this.Ques =res;
      this.setquestions(this.Ques)
               }); 

    this.checklistservice.getQuestions(1).subscribe(res =>{ 
      this.Questions = res;
    console.log(this.Questions)
  }); 

   this.Questions.forEach(q => {
   this.choices = q.choices;
     });
                }


    ngOnChanges() {

                  }


              CreateForm() {
      this.CheckListForm = this.fb.group({

     name: ['', Validators.required],
     EmploymentType: ['', Validators.required],
     HRMS: ['', Validators.required],
     CompanyName:'',
    questions: this.fb.array([]) 
                        })
                           }

          get questions(): FormArray {
        return this.CheckListForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
                                     }


  setquestions(questions: Questions[]) {
  const QuestionsFGs = questions.map(questions => this.fb.group(questions));
  const QuestionsFormArray = this.fb.array(QuestionsFGs);
 this.CheckListForm.setControl('questions', QuestionsFormArray);
                                        }


                                  }
```

Using this codes in my formarray produces radiobuttons with one of the option being checked (only 2 options). I need to design the radiobuttons in such a way that both buttons remain unchecked. This is so that when a user submits the form, unchecked radiobuttons will create a validation error as all form fields are compulsory. 
How to ensure none of the radiobuttons are checked by default?

Comment: Well, make sure that the value of the form control (choices) is not any of the choices of the question (i.e. is null, typically)

Comment: Hi, how do i do that? i do not understand what you mean. How do i then display the choices from the questions?

Comment: Well, when you create your FormControl, in your component TypeScript code, make sure its initial value is null. How to do that depends on how you create your form control. Post the relevant code.

Comment: sure i will do so. please assist. thank you.

Comment: i have added the codes already. Please advice.

Comment: Hi, just to update, i have tried setting the initial value to null in my database. Initial value is now null, but the radiobutton shows an empty field ( no text) with a radiobutton as the initial value. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No response as usual so i will proceed to answer my own question.

To solve this problem, you will need to create new form controls for each question model, in the question array. Set validation.required for the form control.

Then iterate the choices model through the form-controls and the radiobutton is unchecked by default.